# How to set setTimeout/Thread.sleep in newman

Tags: postman, node-modules, newman

How to set setTimeout/Thread.sleep in newman(postman's node module).

I am using below function :

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

        console.log('sleep for ten min');
    }, 600000);
```

Above function works perfectly in collection runner of postman.

But when I tried newman it is throwing error as

> 'setTimeout is not available inside sandbox and has no side-effect.'

I have found a similar thread like below:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/304

But they also haven't provided any solution.

Is there anyway by which I can mark my single API to delay for a time period.

I am already using Newman parameter `--delay-request 60000` which delay between API's so it won't work for it.

[image]

Any solution will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update newman to 3.8.3 or later.

The older version of newman is not supporting setTimeout

Comment: Good you've find :) Maybe others will encounter the same trouble

Answer (score 3):

So opening the [link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/304) you've given to us they say :

[image]

---

So to be clear, you are going to use `newman` a way it's not designed for.

---

This being said, you can try to implement a custom sleep :

```
function sleep(milisecond) {
  const date = Date.now();

  // Sleep in an *infinite* loop
  while ((date + milisecond) > Date.now());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregory .. I have tried that too earlier .. I found the solution ..  testing it ..  will post once confirm.. vote you up for help ;)